# How to add objects to a queue with generic type using reflection?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a generic save/load system for my game in Godot using C#.

I want to support saving of objects that have queues as a property. Since the game code has many classes, I would prefer to avoid duplicating same/similar save/load code for each different class. Therefore, I have a main util class that handles properties with different types when saving and loading. The normal types like int, string, enum, etc. are working fine.

Basically, I have a `BankAccount` class, which has a property `Queue<Expense>`

I'm doing the following steps:

1. When saving the game, I create a dictionary for each object with the property name as the key and the JSON string as the value.
2. If the property is a queue, I convert the contents of the queue to a (temporary) dictionary with the index as the key and the JSON text of the object as value and then use `json.stringify` to convert it to JSON.
3. That is then saved into the `BankAccount` dictionary using the name of the `Queue<Expense>` field.

All that works fine.

4. Upon loading, I reverse that process and first recreate the `BankAccount` object, which initializes the `Queue<Expense>` property so it is ready to be filled.
5. I recreate the dictionary with index as key and JSON string for the objects as value.
6. Using the JSON string from dict value, I recreate the `Expense` objects for each index that needs to go into the queue.
7. However, I cannot find a way to put the created `Expense` objects into the queue, as I cannot cast the initialized queue property to the correct generic type.

If I cast it to just `Queue`, I get:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1[scripts.finance.Expense]' to type
> 'System.Collections.Queue'.

If I cast it to `Queue<object>`, I get:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1[scripts.finance.Expense]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1[System.Object]'.

This is what the relevant piece of my load method looks like:

```cs
if( propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsGenericType && 
    propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Queue<>) ) {
            
    Type genericArgument = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

    Variant variant = Json.ParseString(stringVal);

    Godot.Collections.Dictionary<string, Variant> queueDict = (Godot.Collections.Dictionary<string, Variant>)variant;
        
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Variant> pair  in queueDict) {

        string queueElementString = (string)pair.Value;

        object queueObject = CreateDefaultObject(queueElementString);
                
        Queue<object> queue = (Queue<object>)propertyInfo.GetValue(newObject);

        queue.Enqueue(queueObject);
    }
    return true;
}
```

At this point, `newObject` is my newly created `BankAccount` object, `queueObject` is my newly created `Expense` object. I cannot figure out how to call `Enqueue(queueObject)` on the `Queue<Expense>` property of the `BankAccount` object.

I also tried to get the method and invoke it, using:

```cs
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(Queue).GetMethod("Enqueue");
object invoke = methodInfo.Invoke(propertyInfo.GetValue(newObject), new object[] { queueObject });
```

However, I got the following exception in that case:

> ERROR: System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target
> type.

(same if I try to use `typeof(Queue<object>).GetMethod("Enqueue");` instead)

So, I'm trying to understand, is there a way to add an object to a generic queue, without knowing the generic type at compile time?

If that is not possible, any other suggestions how I could implement my game load without having to implement separate load code for each class with a queue or list?

Comment: I would recommend to scrap all this and use a well-established serialization format instead ( json, mempack, protobuf, ... ).

Comment: i think misteke is in object invoke =
 You need something like you did but without assigning it to object type - what reason ? - you want just call it imho try as You did but with just methodInfo.Invoke(propertyInfo.GetValue(newObject), new object[] { queueObject }); and this why You get  Object does not match target type.

Comment: @Fildor, can you point me to any examples how that could be done?

Comment: @Dorian, I did not understand what you mean. The line you posted is the same as what I tried. What is the difference you suggest?

Comment: Try methodInfo.Invoke(propertyInfo.GetValue(newObject), new object[] { .... Instead of object invoke = methodInfo.Invoke(propertyInfo.GetValue(newObject), new object[] { ... Thats what i mean :)

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean now, but it doesn't make a difference. I was just assigning the return value to see what it would give me back, but it makes no difference, ends up in the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

Following Bisjob's comment, I modified my invoke to the following, and it works:

```cs
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(Queue<>).MakeGenericType(genericArgument).GetMethod("Enqueue");
methodInfo.Invoke(propertyInfo.GetValue(newObject), new object[] { queueObject });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to construct your complete queue type ?

```
var queueType = typeof(Queue<>).MakeGenericType(genericArgument);
var myQueue = Activator.CreateInstance(queueType);
var insertMI = queueType.GetMethod("Enqueue");
insertMI.Invoke(myQueue, new[] { queueObject });
```

But you are mixing `Queue<object>` with `Queue<SomeType>` which are completelly different and you can not make a cast between them.
Instead you should use

```
Queue<object> queue1 = new();
Queue<SomeType> queue2 = queue1.Cast<SomeType>();
```

But it will returns an IEnumerable

Comment: Thanks so much, MakeGenericType is what I needed!

First, I tried to initialize the queue in that function itself, which worked. After that, I tried to modify my invoke code using MakeGenericType and that worked as well. I will prefer to keep that so that each class can initialized their collections.

Thank you so much, I've been struggling with this for days, and finally the solution here within hours!